# How to Determine the Available versions of Firebase

Tags: firebase, polymer

I would like to know how to get the latest version of Firebase. How would I select from latest, beta, or stable versions?
As of now, I believe the latest Firebase is version 3.5.1. I am not even sure.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/releases

Comment: Firebase doesn't publish "latest" or "beta" versions at the moment. The latest release version is available from the link cartant gave or by looking at the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup. The latter says 3.5.0 right now, which should be updated soon (we simply don't always republish all docs for a bugfix release).

Comment: @cartant you might want to post that (with some extra text) as an answer. Simply because I don't know waht else the answer would be. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Firebase releases, for all platforms, are listed in the release notes, which can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases).

If you are using the NPM-distributed Firebase, you can run the following command to see the latest version:

```
 npm view firebase version dist-tags
```

Which effects the following output:

```
version = '3.5.1'
dist-tags =
{ latest: '3.5.1',
  '1.2.0-beta.1-0': '1.2.0-beta.1-0',
  '1.2.0-beta.2': '1.2.0-beta.2',
  '1.2.0-beta.3': '1.2.0-beta.3' }
```

Note that `dist-tags` includes the latest, stable release and some very old betas. As mentioned in the comments, the latest, stable release is the only Firebase release. If `beta` or `next` versions were to be released, they would typically be listed in the `dist-tags`.